# Recreating a HashSet in the ArrayList of HashSets

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I have in code

```
List<HashSet<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>(50);
pos = 17; // just some index less than 50
list.add(pos, new HashSet<Integer>());
list.get(17).add(99);
list.get(17).add(88);
```

After a while I want to remove the HashSet with {99, 88} inside and create a new one, like this:

```
// pos is still here
list.add(pos, new HashSet<Integer>());
```

Is it allowed? Do you know any faster solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.add(pos, new HashSet<Integer>());` is going to [add a new set at that position and shift the existing one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) to `pos+1`. That does not seem to be what you want.

If you want to replace the set by a new one, use `set`:

```
list.set(pos, new HashSet<Integer>());
```

In terms of performance, `ArrayList#set` runs in constant time so it is an efficient way of replacing the existing set in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the contents of a set you can do this

```
Set<Integer> set = list.get(pos);
set.clear();
set.add(99); set.add(98);
```

This is slightly more efficient as it reuses the set.

Answer (score 0):

And if you use **guava**, you can say more concisely:

```
List<Set<Integer>> list = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(50);
list.set(17, Sets.newHashSet(99, 88));
```

Comment: `newArrayListWithCapacity` does not seem to me very concise.

Comment: True, but you loose half of the generics crud when you define list and get a tighter initialization of the member sets, so all in all its a good deal I think.